# Ruby on Rails. Pass variable from views to transaction controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, transactions, controller, cart

I'm trying to set up a simple cart. 
I have followed a tutorial to set up the cart and I am trying to connect this up to Braintree.
The cart functionality works, and Braintree payments work (If I enter a number as the amount), but I am having problems sending the cart total price variable over to the transactions controller.
My code so far:

cart index.html

```
<div class="cart-item-container">
<%= link_to 'Empty your cart', cart_clear_path %>
<br>
<br>
<% tokentotal = 0 %>
<% total = 0 %>
<ul> <% @cart.each do | id, quantity | %>
  <% product = Product.find_by_id(id) %>
<% if quantity != 0 %>
  <li class="cart-items">
    <%= link_to product.title, product %>
    <p><%= product.description %></p>
    <p><%= number_to_currency(product.price, :unit => '€') %></p>
    <p>Quantity<%= quantity %></p>
    <a href="/cart/remove/<%= product.id %>"> Remove from cart</a>
  </li>

  <% total += quantity * product.price %>
  <% tokentotal += quantity * product.tokens %>

  <p>Total <%= number_to_currency(total, :unit => '€') %></p>
  <p> Tokens <%= tokentotal %></p>

</ul>
<% end %>  <%end%>
</div>

<form id="checkout" method="post" action="/transactions">
  <div id="payment-form"></div>
  <%= form_tag transactions_path do%>
    <%# render 'customer_form' unless current_user.has_payment_info? %>
    <div id="dropin">    <p>Please enter your payment details:</p>
</div>
    <%=submit_tag "Pay", class: "button mt1" %>
  <% end %>

</form>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function setupBT() {
    braintree.setup("<%=@client_token%>", 'dropin', {
      container: 'dropin'
    });
  }
  if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", setupBT, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", setupBT);
  else window.onload = setupBT;
  </script>
</script>
```

This shows the total price of the items that are paced in the cart. I would like a way to pass <% total %> over to the 'amount' section of the transaction controller.  I have tried many variations but have left it blank in this example.

Transaction controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!


  def new
end

def create
  unless current_user.has_payment_info?
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
                amount: ,
                payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce],
                customer: {
                  first_name: params[:first_name],
                  last_name: params[:last_name],
                  company: params[:company],
                  email: current_user.email,
                  phone: params[:phone]
                },
                options: {
                  store_in_vault: true
                })
  else
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
                amount: ,
                payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce])
  end


  if @result.success?
    session[:cart] = nil
    Token.create(user_id: current_user.id)
    redirect_to new_gig_path, notice: "Congraulations! Your transaction has been successfully!"
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong while processing your transaction. Please try again!"
    render :new
  end
end


private


def token_params
  params.require(:token).permit(:user_id)
end
private
def generate_client_token
  if current_user.has_payment_info?
    Braintree::ClientToken.generate(customer_id: current_user.braintree_customer_id)
  else
    Braintree::ClientToken.generate
  end
end
end
```

The cart controller:

```
class CartController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
   before_action :find_product


def remove
  id = params[:id]
  if session[:cart] then
    cart = session[:cart]
  else
    session[:cart] = {}
    cart = session[:cart]
  end
  if cart[id] then
    cart[id] = cart[id] - 1
  else
    cart[id] = 1
end
redirect_to :action => :index
end

  def add
    id = params[:id]
    #if cart already created use exisiing one
    if session[:cart] then
      cart = session[:cart]
    else
      session[:cart] = {}
      cart = session[:cart]
    end
    #if token already in cart increase value
    if cart[id] then
      cart[id] = cart[id] + 1
    else
      cart[id] = 1
    end
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end #end add method

  def clearCart
    session[:cart] = nil
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end



  def index
    if current_user.has_payment_info?
    @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate(customer_id: current_user.braintree_customer_id)
  else
    @client_token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate
  end
    #if there is a cart, pass it to the page for display else pass empty value
    if session[:cart] then
      @cart = session[:cart]
    else
      @cart = {}
    end
end


private

def find_product
@product = Product.find_by_id(params[:id])
end

end
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hidden field in your form to send amount over to controller.

```
<form id="checkout" method="post" action="/transactions">
  <div id="payment-form"></div>
  <%= form_tag transactions_path do%>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'amount', total %>
    <%# render 'customer_form' unless current_user.has_payment_info? %>
    <div id="dropin">    <p>Please enter your payment details:</p>
</div>
    <%=submit_tag "Pay", class: "button mt1" %>
  <% end %>

</form>
```

Comment: So simple. This has worked perfectly, thank you. (Added params[:amount] to the controller).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted `@archana`'s answer to be even more succinct, you could pass the param to the [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) helper:

```
<%= button_to "Pay", transaction_path, params: { amount: total } %>
```

This will create a form with the `amount` hidden input, passing the value to the controller.